# How to make 'self' in parent class refer to extended class in PHP?

Tags: php, factory, dry, self, late-static-binding

I'm working with Wordpress and need to instantiate a new class similar to this oversimplified example (for an `add_action()` hook which receives some arguments):

```
class A {
        public function __construct() {
        }

        public static function init() {
                $instance = new self();
                $instance->doStuff();
        }

        protected function doStuff() {
                echo get_class($this);
        }
}

class B extends A {
}

B::init(); //returns 'A'
```

How can I get `self` in `init()` to refer to extended classes when called from them? I'm aware of the [late static bindings page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) in the PHP docs, but I'm not clear on how to apply it in the above context. Thanks!

Comment: Because B extends A and you haven't implemented function `init` in class B, it's searching for the implementation to parent class.

Comment: I had considered that, but it's not very dry. So, is the best way then, to just override A::init() by rewriting the entire init() function in class B?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou that's not what's happening - the problem is `self` will always refer to the class the code lives in, so `new self()` instantiated A.

Comment: @HorusKol i was wrong, you gave good solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```php
public static function init() {
    $instance = new static();
    $instance->doStuff();
}
```

You can see this working on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/Nc91i), which is a great place to sandbox some PHP.

Why `static`? You were right to look at the [PHP manual for late static bindings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), and it's a shame the page doesn't explicitly mention this specific use of the static keyword (though, there's a comment that does).

In the context of late static bindings, you can replace `self` with `static`, and it will use the instantiated class, whereas `self` would use the class the code lives in. For example:

```php
<?php
class A {

}

class B extends A {
    public function test() {
        echo parent::class;
        echo self::class;
        echo static::class;
    }
}
class C extends B {

}

$c = new C();
$c->test();
```

This even works in a static context (unfortunately, the static keyword is used in two different contexts: static calls, and late static binding), as per my example above.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me, @HorusKol! I appreciate you! :)